# ROS2 Navigation2: Local Plan does not Avoid Obstacle

Tags: navigation, ros2, ros-humble, nav2, turtlebot3

In ROS 2 Humble, I'm seeing behavior from the Nav2 DWB controller that fails to successfully plan a path. Lots of `No valid trajectories out of 419!` are in the logs when this occurs.

Attached are screenshots showing that the DWB planner isn't even considering trajectories that might go around the obstacle.

[image: rviz showing trajectories]
[image: rviz showing plans]

Note that the global costmap has its obstacle layer disabled, so the global plan does go straight through the obstacle. However, the local plan should still go around. Also, this is a differential-drive robot, and the trajectories do not show rotation before movement as an option.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? My nav2 parameters are as follows (nearly default):

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: -1.0 #100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "beam" #"likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 360 #60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node

bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] # "precise_goal_checker"
    current_goal_checker: "general_goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    #precise_goal_checker:
    #  plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
    #  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  stateful: True
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 6.28
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      # As described here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/576
      max_speed_xy: 100.0
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.22
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          sensor_frame: base_scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.22
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: False
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          sensor_frame: base_scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    # Overridden in launch by the "map" launch configuration or provided default value.
    # To use in yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py file & provide full path to map below.
    yaml_filename: ""
    frame_id: "map"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True
    robot_base_frame: "base_link"

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.26, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.26, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0
```

edit: Issue still occurs even after re-enabling the global costmap's obstacle layer. Note the global path going around the obstacle:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to start off by reading the DWA paper [1]. Its uncharacteristically approachable for a foundational robotics paper & it'll help you understand what the Dynamic Window Approach is actually doing.

It looks from your image that your only setting trajectory samples in the forward direction. Since your robot is right next to the obstacle, it can't do anything because any motion forward would result in a collision. If you allowed the robot to reverse, then there's a non-invalid option it can use.

But, this touches upon an important property of **Reactive** techniques like DWA (which is why its worth at least skimming the paper). They only look at the current timesteps snapshot to select the trajectory that is best then-and-there, without consideration of past or future timesteps.

This is a key benefit to MPC, MPPI, or similar **Predictive** techniques. They can make suboptimal choices (like reversing) in the short term in order to set the problem up for a more successful outcome in the future. Reactive single-shot methods like DWA cannot, since its trying to maximize value here-and-now. Still, the Predictive method needs to be setup to be able to reverse, which if setup exactly like your DWA config here would also struggle. The trajectory generation method can only produce candidates within the bounds you specify and if the robot is going to get up close and personal with obstacles, you need to give it the tools it needs to get out of those situations.

Though Predictive isn't all rainbows and sunshine, there are computational and behavioral constraint limitations emposed by those frameworks. Generally, if you have the compute to run them and you want highly dynamic behavior, they're a good bet. But, for all of DWA's potential downfalls, its substantially computationally less expensive and can be run at a faster rate due to it, which as long as you have recoveries or have applications / constraints that don't put robots into situations that their algorithms are weak for, is a nice attribute since you can use that compute elsewhere instead.

That's a round about way to say that you should allow DWB to have reversing samples so it can get out of situations like this or consider Predictive techniques that are going to handle close encounters of this kind with more grace -- if handling situations like this are truly in your application requirements and not just a toy example.

[1] https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub1/fox_dieter_1997_1/fox_dieter_1997_1.pdf

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your very thorough response. I did take your advice, and I enabled backwards movement by setting the min_vel_x parameter to -0.26. I can see that DWB now generates backwards trajectories. However, it does not follow them. (see https://imgur.com/ZAShM8M)

I'll give the paper a read in a minute. It seems that the robot should be able to first rotate and then plan a trajectory.

Comment: That is then likely now a gain tuning problem of the various critics!

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help! I will play around with it.

For now, I've now reset the critic gains to default values, have re-enabled the global obstacle layer, and am using the ["rotation shim controller"](https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-rotation-shim-controller.html) coupled with DWB to perform rotation before enabling DWB control. Results seem good enough for the time being!

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to **increase** these values (max_range):

```
  data_type: "LaserScan"
  raytrace_max_range: 3.0
  raytrace_min_range: 0.0
  obstacle_max_range: 2.5
  obstacle_min_range: 0.0
```

The scan range is too low (for global costmap, for local maybe it is ok). Maybe your robot perceives the obstacle when it is too close to it. Then for it to follow the path, it will need to enter a recovery behavior, such as spinning or going backward, and this approach won't work so smoothly and functionally...

In addition, why did you set this value so high:

```
max_speed_xy: 100.0
```

To debug it I would also perform a

```
ros2 topic echo /cmd_vel
```

to check if your robot is sending just linear velocity in x **and not angular in Z** to enable the robot to head to the produced path.

Finally, as Steve said you can **fine-tune the params** of global and/or local planners. If DWB is not working just use [MPPI](https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-mppic.html) as the local planner or **try other compatible global/local planners** with nav2